How to disable token renewals in HashiCorp vault agent
I need to reduce a number of login and renew requests into the vault server. My vault agent is using approle auth method.
I was able to manage login cnt by increasing token_max_ttl in approle config:
token_max_ttl = "6h"

To reduce renew requests I set token_ttl to the same value as token_max_ttl.
token_ttl     = "6h"
token_max_ttl = "6h"

My idea was since token TTL equals to max TTL, it doesn't make sense to renew a token at all, cause it wouldn't help to prolong the session. But vault agent doesn't agree to me. And it does renew it several times. At least tries:
2024-08-18T22:12:25.534Z [INFO]  agent.auth.handler: renewed auth token
2024-08-18T22:12:25.537Z [INFO]  agent.auth.handler: lifetime watcher done channel triggered
2024-08-18T22:12:25.537Z [INFO]  agent.auth.handler: authenticating
2024-08-18T22:12:25.728Z [INFO]  agent.auth.handler: authentication successful, sending token to sinks
2024-08-18T22:12:25.728Z [INFO]  agent.auth.handler: starting renewal process
2024-08-18T22:12:25.730Z [INFO]  agent.sink.file: token written: path=/token/token_file
2024-08-18T22:12:25.838Z [INFO]  agent.auth.handler: renewed auth token
2024-08-19T02:35:54.214Z [INFO]  agent.auth.handler: renewed auth token
2024-08-19T02:35:54.215Z [INFO]  agent.auth.handler: lifetime watcher done channel triggered
2024-08-19T02:35:54.215Z [INFO]  agent.auth.handler: authenticating
2024-08-19T02:35:54.386Z [INFO]  agent.auth.handler: authentication successful, sending token to sinks
2024-08-19T02:35:54.386Z [INFO]  agent.auth.handler: starting renewal process
2024-08-19T02:35:54.387Z [INFO]  agent.sink.file: token written: path=/token/token_file
2024-08-19T02:35:54.502Z [INFO]  agent.auth.handler: renewed auth token
2024-08-19T06:58:35.020Z [INFO]  agent.auth.handler: renewed auth token
2024-08-19T06:58:35.023Z [INFO]  agent.auth.handler: lifetime watcher done channel triggered
2024-08-19T06:58:35.023Z [INFO]  agent.auth.handler: authenticating
2024-08-19T06:58:35.173Z [INFO]  agent.auth.handler: authentication successful, sending token to sinks
2024-08-19T06:58:35.174Z [INFO]  agent.auth.handler: starting renewal process
2024-08-19T06:58:35.176Z [INFO]  agent.sink.file: token written: path=/token/token_file
2024-08-19T06:58:35.288Z [INFO]  agent.auth.handler: renewed auth token

Out of the logs I see that every 4h23m it does the following:
 1. Tries to renew.                 Not sure why, but ok.
 2. Lifetime watch triggers.        Why after 4h23m, not 5h30m for instance?
 3. Authenticates for a new token.  OK
 4. Renews the token right away.    This I do not understand at all

Based on the situation I have two questions:

How to disable token renewal entirely or at least partially.
How to manage when lifetime check triggers. I could deal with it using max_ttl. But it would be nicer if I can specify: trigger 30 min before expiration or 10% of TTL before expiration.

Thanks!

Disabling the token renewal requires setting the token_explicit_max_ttl for the token associated with the AppRole authentication role in the config. It is demonstrated in the question that you already know how to modify these settings. This specific setting would enable a "hard cap" on the token beyond which it cannot be renewed.
Configuring the lifetime check renewal frequency timing requires setting the token_period for the token similar to the above. Note that modifying this period timing for the token in combination with the explicit max ttl may seem as if the period could circumvent the "hard cap", but:

A token with both a period and an explicit max TTL will act like a periodic token but will be revoked when the explicit max TTL is reached

An in-depth discussion of token lifetimes and timings can be found in the relevant Vault documentation.

Thanks for the answer! I was reading the docs for a couple days, but still cannot wrap my head around it. Particularly, what's the difference between max_ttl and explicit_max_ttl? It seems like the smaller value will be used. So I don't get why having two. Unfortunately I cannot freely experiment with a corporate vault storage. When I have time I will try to setup a dev vault installation and experiment there. I feel like your suggestion might actually work. I'm just missing a good example to really understand it.

@SergeyBelonozhko I can understand how the documentation may be less clear to someone approaching this for the first time. The max_ttl is the time to live for the token per renewal, and the explicit_max_ttl is the time to live for the token regardless.
